# How to upgrade from iOS 4 to iOS 6 without losing app data

Tags: ios, ipad, backup, upgrade

I am still on iOS 4, and I understand that I need to erase my iPad before upgrading. But I don't want to lose the game data stored locally, particularly Candy Crush. :) Is there a way to preserve data while upgrading?

Comment: As an aside, your Candy Crush progress is stored outside of the game and would be restored once you log back into the game after upgrading. That said, most apps/games do not work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a backup and then restore the backup once the update has finished.

A step by step guide is available here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4972, which states the following:

*To update your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch from iOS 4 to iOS 5 or later, you must erase and restore your device first, before completing the update.*

As part of the update and restore process, iTunes will (in order):

- Back up key elements of your device, such as settings, Contacts,
  Calendars, Notes, and your Camera Roll. iTunes will not, however,
  back up media content from your iOS device, such as music, apps,
  books, movies, and TV shows.
- Update your device to the latest version of iOS software.
- Restore your device from your most recent backup.
- Restart your device.
- Sync back media content from your iTunes Library to your device.

Answer (score -2):

make a back up then restore and use the backup to get all of your data back